# Desktop only: Display multiple one-row tables

Tags: tables, data-tables, data, information

I couldn't find a fitting solution to that so I am asking for your guys opinions - what is the best way to display multiple one-row tables?

Since there is a lot of other information behind each row, it is not possible to display them underneath each other like regular tables. The information needs to fit into  a rectangle, since the other related information is placed on the same space "on the backside". So I thought of descunstructing the table. Colors are just for showing you that there are kind of categories:

[image: Deconsctructed table]

Another approach would be to display a regular scrollable table with filters, but as you can imagine the space between each row would be huge since the other information behind. Also I would like to avoid horizontal scrolling:

[image: Huge Table]

The application will be desktop only. Is the first approach in your opinion valid? There is a lot of information which can be confusing, on the other hand its all at glance which is pretty important here. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What are the users doing with this info?

Comment: And what do you mean by 'other information behind'? It's a little unclear at the moment.

Comment: A less abstract example might be beneficial here to decide on the content placement. How big can the "content" be?

Answer (score 1):

Rather old question.
More info on what's the nature of data would help.

Sounds like you have a lot of categorized properties for every topic. Like properties of a product: weight, size, dimension.

Therefore, althow it sounds obvious, you should rotate your table 90 deg to make topics be columns and properties - rows.

If there is no need to see all categories at once, you may try tabs to show only one categoy at a time:

[image]